# El método de una clase devuelve un DataFrame vacío

Tags: python-3.7, jupyter

Practicando clases. Disponemos de la clase 'market_data = MarketData'. En ella, dos métodos devuelven correctamente los DataFrames 'self.portfolio_r4_df' y 'self.yf_index_df'.

Con el método siguiente.

```
# DataFrame con índices y valores.
def get_index_value_df(self):
    #self. df_total = self.portfolio_r4_df.join(self.yf_index_df)
    self.df_total = pd.concat([self.portfolio_r4_df, self.yf_index_df], axis=1) 
    return self.df_total
```

Invocado como muestro a continuación:

```
#  Creating the class object
market_data =  MarketData()
# Select start and end dates of the analysis
start_date, end_date = market_data.get_start_end_dates() 
df_total = market_data.get_index_value_df()
df_total[:3]
```

No me devuelve nada.

Hago la prueba de unirlos con ésta sentencia.

```
df_total = portfolio_r4_df.join(yf_index_df)
```

y devuelve un 'df_total' correctamente.

¿Cuál es la causa de éste fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: de donde saca la variable `pd`? ya que por lo que veo esta dentro del scope de la funcion solamente...

Comment: Se define en la importación de módulos 'import pandas as pd'. La clase es muy larga y he filtrado métodos y obviadola importación de módulos.